# Check if there were any errors during validation

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I'm trying to pick up C#, doing some basic validation stuff at the moment.

So, I'm using the errorProvider control but when I press the OK button in my form, the form just submits. Yeah, the error icons appear where they should (validation works) but how can I check if there were actually any errors so I can prevent the form from being submitted? Please try to be as noob-friendly as possible, I barely understand any C#.

Comment: Asp.net? silverlight? WPF? winforms? (the main reason  for my downvote, the secondary is the lack of code)

Comment: Can you show your onvalidation handler? I suspect you're not setting e.cancel = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an error provider and handling onvalidating, it should look like this:

```
    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Please leave this textbox blank!");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "");
        }
    }
```

This will prevent you clicking off the control

Alternatively, implement the ok button click handler like this:

```
    private void OkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Validate())
        {
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;
        }

    }
```

The "DialogResult = none" business is what stops the form closing.

Comment: If this fixed the issue, can I get an accept please?

Comment: Have an upvote just in case. Clean, concise answer.

Comment: tried to but I have to wait couple more mins. It seems like I'm still having a problem though. My validating method has the second parameter of type EventArgs but in your example it's CancelEventArgs. However, if I try to modify it accordingly, some errors show up because of this line I believe: this.firstName_textbox.Validated += new System.EventHandler(this.validate_notEmpty);

Comment: Ok, you've subscribed to the "Validat*ED*" event, you need the "Validat*ING*" event. The Validated event happens AFTER the validating has happened

Comment: Still getting "No overload for 'validate_notEmpty' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'" though.

Comment: ok, do this. Select the control in the design view. Right click and select properties. Then, look for the little lightning bolt. This displays a list of available events. Scroll to find the one that says validating and double click. This will create the validating event handler and subscribe it all for you in one neat motion

Comment: Can't find any 'little lighting bolt' in the proprieties panel. Can you name it? Sorry to bother, if you're busy or something just nevermind.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/PropertyHeaderWM/img9.PNG fourth icon from the left...

Comment: form load and button click are the only events available. should I choose the button click one?

Comment: nope, youve got the form selected. click the control youre interested in and there are tons of events

Comment: actually when I selected the form I got tons of events =]. if I click the error control there are only those 2 available. anyways, we kinda chatted here but I appreciate your help, also accepted the answer, thanks. edit: finally got it, I had to add the validating method to the textbox validating's event, not the form's.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of validation. Please read this article to start and many questions will be disapear http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx